# Padding inside tables doesn't work in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, padding

I created a table and I assigned to each tag 
  `<td>`
the class "product_page": `<td class="product_page">`

The TD is referred to the following CSS lines:

```
.post td.product_page {
width:33%;
padding:20px 15px 5px 15px;
vertical-align:top;
border:1px solid #666;
}
```

Now, the tag "padding" doesn't have any effect in Chrome. The text contained in the `<td></td>`has not margin from the table border.
All the other instructions contained in the box above, are working perfectly.

What's wrong please ?
I thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you supply a jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 2):

I created [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MarbleStrain/d2BRU/) and it seems to be working correctly. I am using chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure td.product_page is inside something marked .post.

Also,  try using margins.